# Dummy arguments in lambdas that will match any type?

Tags: c++, lambda

Suppose I have something like this:

```
struct Foo {};
struct Bar {};
struct Baz {};

// ...

void RegisterListener1(std::function<void(Foo)>);
void RegisterListener2(std::function<void(Bar)>);
void RegisterListener3(std::function<void(Baz)>);
```

Where there is no relationship between `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Baz`.

Now, suppose I'd like to pass each of these Register functions an identical lambda that *ignores its argument*. Is there anything I can put in the lambda's argument list that means "match anything here; I'm just going to throw the thing out anyway"?

```
auto listener = []( /* what? */ ) { throw UnsupportedOperationException(); };
RegisterListener1( listener );
RegisterListener2( listener );
RegisterListener3( listener );
```

I could use a function template instead of a lambda and do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
void listener(T)
{
   throw UnsupportedOperationException();
}

// ...

RegisterListener1( listener<Foo> );
RegisterListener2( listener<Bar> );
RegisterListener3( listener<Baz> );
```

But that's tedious, especially if the functor arguments to the three Register functions are templated themselves such that there's no easy way to write out the "inner" argument types. Here is another idea that occurred to me in the process of typing this up:

```
struct Anything
{
    template<typename T> Anything(const T&) {}
};

// ...

auto listener = [](Anything) { throw UnsupportedOperationException(); }; 
RegisterListener1( listener );
RegisterListener2( listener );
RegisterListener3( listener );
```

I'm actually ok with that, and maybe I don't need to ask the question anymore, but is there an even better option?

Comment: If you are creating a struct you may as well ditch the lambda and just use a functor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++14, you can `[](auto&&){ throw UnsupportedOperationException(); }`.

In C++03 you can:

```
struct ignore_and_throw {
  template<class T>
  void operator()(T const&) const {
    throw UnsupportedOperationException();
  }
};
```

and pass `ignore_and_throw()` as your listener.  This function object has a `template` `operator()` which you don't have to specify the arguments to, saving you the annoying type-name retype.  (`ignore_and_throw` is very similar to what the C++14 lambda produces as an aside).

Your `Anything` should probably be called `sink_and_ignore` or `ignore_arg`, and is acceptable.

Comment: You said C++03 but probably meant C++11, since you used a rvalue reference. However, for ignored arguments `const&` should work just as well and really works in C++03.

Comment: @oberon yep, I just type `T&&` when I don't care automatically nowadays.  :)